# invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx server but I'm following the official documentation after reloading Nginx, I faced this alarm:

`invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9`

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
events{}


http{
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        server{listen 80;
              server_name x.x.x.x;
              root /var/www/html/;
              try_files /error;


              location =rediect {return 307 http://www.facebook.com;}
              location /error {return 200 "we overcome the error ";}
              location =/right{ return 200 "you are right"; }
              location =/time{return 200 "$time_local";}
              location =/host{return 200 "$hostname";}
              location =/redirect{return 301 http://www.facebook.com;}
             #location / {access_log /var/log/nginx/new.log;}
              location / {access_log /var/log/nginx/last.log ;}
             }
   } 

**Where is x.x.x.x is my machine ip.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Get used to reading [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/), especially for straight forward questions like that.  I get that you're new to nginx, but googling "nginx try_files" would have been a lot quicker than typing the question in here.

Anyway, you would have ended up here:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

> Syntax:   try_files file ... uri;
>
> Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.